# SonarQube version 5.2 build breaker plugin alternative

Tags: jenkins, build, sonarqube

Build breaker support seems to have discontinued 5.2 onwards. Is there any other Jenkins plugin which will help me achieve a build fail if quality metrics are not met.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to SonarQube 5.3, you can use this new Quality Web Service API:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Breaking+the+CI+Build

to break your build if your quality gate fails.

Comment: Thanks David. I have upgraded to 5.3 as per your advice. But I'm not sure how to use the Quality Web Service API to break the build as I wasn't able to find any steps in the SonarQube documentation. Will you be able to point me in the right direction? Thanks!

p.s.- I'm a novice with the development part, any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: I have a Jenkins/Maven/WildFly setup and what I'm trying to do is to tell Jenkins to break the build when quality gate fails.

Comment: So I haven't come up with the best strategy to complete the task yet (still thinking about it), but in your Jenkins job, right before the status of the job is complete, you should see a section: [INFO] More about the report processing at http://insert-server-ip-here:9000/api/ce/task?id=insert-ce-id-here

If you go to that URL, you can see a JSON object, look for analysisID. Then go to http://insert-server-ip-here:9000/api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=insert-analysis-id-here

If you go there, you will see STATUS. Based on that, you decide if you fail the build.

Comment: Furthermore, once running a build on the new server, login to your CI server (jenkins server) and go to `cd /` and run `sudo find . -name "report-task.txt"` and you should see the report generated. You can write a bash script to continually search this file for the id; then curl the above addresses looking for specific responses; and when your done, delete the file, awaiting a new one to be generated

Comment: all that would leave is how to fail the build from your jenkins machine...thinking :)

Comment: actually i have another suggestion:
1. Create a second job inside of Jenkins, that will execute a script
2. Run your analysis same as before inside of Jenkins, but add a POST BUILD step, that will run the job created in 1. 
3. The script inside of 1 should extract the ceTaskURL from the location on your Jenkins server, then curl this URL (you might need to provide --user user:pass for your curl command), then extract the analysisID, curl the next website to get the status, and if successful, exit 0, else exit 1. This will mean it will take 2 jenkins jobs to get a true status of success

Comment: just found out theres a way in Jenkins to add a post build step, which if fails, can fail the original job. so scratch my last sentence in last comment (sorry for so many comments). kind of thinking out loud here. But this is the strategy I am going to use, so it should work perfectly for you

Comment: Thanks so much David for your advise, I'm gonna try it today and and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: awesome, and with my last comment (i.e. scratch the last sentence) that also means you won't need a new job in jenkins

Comment: in other words, just run a post build step which is a shell script, the shell script will be a script to execute the file i said that does all the stuff above

Comment: I finally got to implementing this today (have been caught up with other task!). Unfortunately http://http://myip:9000/api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=4494 doesnt work. I tried different combinations as well but no luck.
TIA

Comment: The post build shell script is unfortunately run *before* the post build action Sonar, so this doesn’t work…

Comment: I run my sonar analysis during the build; inside of the `goals and options` textbox of the `build` section I have `sonar:sonar` and I have inside of my pom.xml the necessary sonar and jacoco properties and execution targets

Comment: and if yo dont' want to switch to this method, you can add another post `build action: build other projects` where this project executes the script i have explained above, exiting with a status of 1 when the quality gate failed and 0 when it succeeded

Answer (score 1):

I used the [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) to get the functionality in SonarQube 5.3.

The following code breaks the build if anything goes wrong or the quality gate check fails:

```java
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

// shortcut to make writing to the log easier
def log = manager.listener.logger.&println
// this gets the filepath to the workspace
// note that FilePath can also reference remote files
def workspace = manager.build.getWorkspace()
def reportPath = workspace.withSuffix("/.sonar/report-task.txt")
log("Reading sonar taskId from file: '${reportPath}'")

// if anything goes wrong the build still needs to fail, therefore failure in the catch block
try
{
    if (!reportPath.exists())
    {
        log("[QualityGate] File '${reportPath}' does not exist. Without URL to check the task status the quality gate can not be checked.")
        manager.buildFailure()
    }
    else
    {
        // retrieve the taskUrl to check the task status
        def report = reportPath.read()
        def properties = new Properties()
        properties.load(report)
        def taskUrl = new URL(properties.ceTaskUrl)

        // used for parsing the response from the server
        def jsonParser = new JsonSlurper()

        def status = "PENDING"
        String analysisId = null
        while (status == "PENDING" || status == "IN_PROGRESS")
        {
            // loop until the task on the server is finished
            log("[QualityGate] Requesting task status from URL: " + properties.ceTaskUrl)
            def response = jsonParser.parse(taskUrl.newReader())
            status = response.task.status
            analysisId = response.task.analysisId
            sleep(1000)
        }

        if (status == "FAILED" || status == "CANCELED")
        {
            log("[QualityGate] Task failed or was canceled.")
            manager.buildFailure()
        }
        else if (status == "SUCCESS")
        {
            // once the task is finished on the server we can check the result
            def analysisUrl = new URL("${properties.serverUrl}/api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=${analysisId}")
            log("[QualityGate] Task finished, checking the result at ${analysisUrl}")
            def result = jsonParser.parse(analysisUrl.newReader())
            if (result.projectStatus.status == "OK")
            {
                log("[QualityGate] Analysis passed the quality gate.")
                manager.buildSuccess()
            }
            else if (result.projectStatus.status == "ERROR")
            {
                log("[QualityGate] Analysis did not pass the quality gate.")
                manager.buildFailure()
            }
            else
            {
                log("[QualityGate] Unknown quality gate status: '${result.projectStatus.status}'")
                manager.buildFailure()
            }
        }
        else
        {
            log("[QualityGate] Unknown task status '${status}. Aborting.")
            manager.buildFailure()
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    log("[QualityGate] Unexpected Exception: " + e.getMessage())
    manager.buildFailure()
}
```

Comment: this is not working in sandbox. can you provide something which work in sandbox?

Comment: i am sorry the script relies on methods not available in sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Although I use 5.1 the logic should be relatively similar. First I use the "resources" API call I.e.,< yourserver:9000/api/resources?resource=projectname&metrics=quality_gate_details> to pull the quality gate measures (metric, pass/fail. scores, etc) for a given project.  I use 'jq' to import the json data in a bash script and figure out (quite easily) which metrics passed/failed, their scores, and so on.

It seems your main aim though is to fail the build manually.  This can be done using the jenkins-cli.jar. The command is "java -jar jenkins-cli.jar set-build-result pass/fail/unstable"

Note that manually setting the build status  this way must be done at build time. You should use it at the end of your build step, after determining if it should be set to failed or unstable.

I hope that helped. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Jdub. I finally reverted to 5.1 and will wait for 5.4 to introduce the plugin.